# How would I go about creating a Cron Job with aMember to push emails to GetResponse?

Tags: php, cron, getresponse, amember

Good Day.
I have a newsletters section in aMember Pro 4 showing all Campaigns from get-response. I have the Plugin configured correctly with GetResponse in aMember with the API key as evident by the correct Campaign titles showing up in CP > Protect Content > Newsletters.

My question is around the functional side with how aMember communicates with GetResponse. How do I setup aMember to "push" notifications to GetResponse when a new member purchases?

Scenario: Customer A signs up for monthly recurring membership. I have Category "Monthly Recurring" setup as a Product married to Monthly_Membership campaign for plugin get-response. That email address and username is "pushed" to get-response to add that email to the campaign list in GetResponse.

How do i make that scenario a reality? I can't seem to find anything in the forums that explains how this works or what I need to do in the CP to make this a reality. Do I have to setup Cron Jobs to do this with my CPanel? Are there tutorials on setting up Cron Jobs for pushing emails to a third-party email campaign company like aWeber or GetResponse?

Thank you for your time. I hope I was concise on what I am needing help with.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

So. It seems with aMember the integration plugin for GetResponse does this automatically, live. No Cron Job needed.

"assigned Monthly_Membership campaign to category 'Monthly Recurring' at
   aMember CP -> Protect Content -> Newsletters" " integration plugin will add/remove subscribers automatically when subscription starts/expires."

Now I just have to figure out how to move customers to an expired campaign or to a Pending campaign if they did not actually purchase a product. I will response in a Comment to this answer once I figure that out.

Cheers!
Jim